# control axes in matplotlib dynamically

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I'm trying to generate a heat map using matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sys
import re

data = np.random.rand(10, 10)
heatmap = plt.pcolor(data)

with open(sys.argv[1],'r') as iFile:
    for line in iFile:
    line=line.strip()
    values=re.split('[-:]',line)
    x=values[0].strip()
    y=values[1].strip()
    z=values[2].strip()
    data[y,x]=z

for y in range(data.shape[0]):
    for x in range(data.shape[1]):
        plt.text(x + 0.5, y + 0.5, '%.2f' % data[y, x],
             horizontalalignment='center',
             verticalalignment='center',)

plt.colorbar(heatmap)
plt.show()
```

and the data is in the "x - y : value" format as follows

```
6 - 4 : 0.180671274019055
6 - 1 : 0.30475569499109
6 - 3 : 0.276460025706412
6 - 2 : 0.298002584369681
...
...
1 - 4 : 0.0961071651182192
1 - 1 : 0.259655770346209
1 - 3 : 0.308485173534571
1 - 2 : 0.278724535194018
```

Question: The x and y values are quite dynamic and can vary (here 1 to 6). I want to dynamically set the axes based on the input file. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyplot has `xlim` and `ylim` functions in its API.

http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xlim
http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.ylim

Also many other axis related manipulation routines if you search around that API page.